# Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression error by JsonConvert.Deserialize()

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, jsonconvert

I get an error from this code:

```
var b = content.FormMasterLists.Where(x => x.FormMasterStatus == "pending");

var c = b.Where(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApprovalCCB>(x.FormMasterApprovalCcb).Group.SelectMany(x => x.Department).SelectMany(x => x.ApprovalCCBLevel).SelectMany(x => x.Approver).Where(x => x.ApproverEmail == "christ").Any());
```

But this code runs successfully:

```
var b = content.FormMasterLists.Where(x => x.FormMasterStatus == "pending").ToList();

var c = b.Where(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApprovalCCB>(x.FormMasterApprovalCcb).Group.SelectMany(x => x.Department).SelectMany(x => x.ApprovalCCBLevel).SelectMany(x => x.Approver).Where(x => x.ApproverEmail == "christ").Any());
```

Is there any way to declare `.Where` without `List()`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to declare .Where without List()?

No way in such implementation. EF Core cannot convert `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to the SQL and provide needed filtering on the server side.

So you have to materialise objects to `IEnumerable` and use client side filtering.

Anyway some databases provide filtering based on JSON content but then you have to create appropriate extension function for EF Core.